# Factory Contract Not generating Tokens

Tags: solidity, tokens, dapps, factory

Hi I am new to DApp development. I am using a Factory contract and that factory contract is creating multiple tokens contract.
When I create a new token contract it generates the transaction but when i add that token address to my account in order to have a look at my generated tokens then it shows up the token information but after adding that token, the total number of the tokens remain 0 not the total supply. Also I cannot send those tokens to any other account because the total number of token is 0.
Given below is the code

Factory Contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

import "./WILDToken.sol";

contract Bakery {

  // index of created contracts

  address[] public contracts;

  // useful to know the row count in contracts index

  function getContractCount() 
    public
    constant
    returns(uint contractCount)
  {
    return contracts.length;
  }

  // deploy a new contract

  function newToken()
    public
    returns(address newContract)
  {
    WILDToken c = new WILDToken();
    contracts.push(c);
    return c;
  }
}
```

Token Contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

/**
 * @title SafeMath
 * @dev Math operations with safety checks that throw on error
 */
library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    uint256 c = a / b;
    // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}

/**
 * @title ERC20Basic
 * @dev Simpler version of ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/179
 */
contract ERC20Basic {
  uint256 public totalSupply;
  function balanceOf(address who) constant returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) returns (bool);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

/**
 * @title Basic token
 * @dev Basic version of StandardToken, with no allowances.
 */
contract BasicToken is ERC20Basic {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping(address => uint256) balances;

  /**
  * @dev transfer token for a specified address
  * @param _to The address to transfer to.
  * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
  */
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool) {
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
  * @param _owner The address to query the the balance of.
  * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
  */
  function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

}

/**
 * @title ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 */
contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) constant returns (uint256);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) returns (bool);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) returns (bool);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

/**
 * @title Standard ERC20 token
 *
 * @dev Implementation of the basic standard token.
 * @dev https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 * @dev Based on code by FirstBlood: https://github.com/Firstbloodio/token/blob/master/smart_contract/FirstBloodToken.sol
 */
contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;


  /**
   * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
   * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
   * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
   * @param _value uint256 the amout of tokens to be transfered
   */
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool) {
    var _allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];

    // Check is not needed because sub(_allowance, _value) will already throw if this condition is not met
    // require (_value <= _allowance);

    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = _allowance.sub(_value);
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Aprove the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
   */
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool) {

    // To change the approve amount you first have to reduce the addresses`
    //  allowance to zero by calling `approve(_spender, 0)` if it is not
    //  already 0 to mitigate the race condition described here:
    //  https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
    require((_value == 0) || (allowed[msg.sender][_spender] == 0));

    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to check the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   * @param _owner address The address which owns the funds.
   * @param _spender address The address which will spend the funds.
   * @return A uint256 specifing the amount of tokens still available for the spender.
   */
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }

}


/**
 * @title SimpleToken
 * @dev Very simple ERC20 Token example, where all tokens are pre-assigned to the creator.
 * Note they can later distribute these tokens as they wish using `transfer` and other
 * `StandardToken` functions.
 */
contract WILDToken is StandardToken {

  string public constant name = "Marshmellow Token";
  string public constant symbol = "MMT";
  uint256 public constant decimals = 18;

  uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 300000000 * 10**18;

  /**
   * @dev Contructor that gives msg.sender all of existing tokens.
   */
  function WILDToken() {
    totalSupply = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
  }

}
```

Any help will be Appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor assigns all the tokens to `msg.sender`. I think that's a pretty reasonable thing to do, but in this case, `msg.sender` is the factory contract.

I would recommend changing the factory contract to transfer all its tokens to you after deploying the token contract:

```
function newToken()
    public
    returns(address newContract)
  {
    WILDToken c = new WILDToken();
    // Send all tokens to the caller
    c.transfer(msg.sender, c.balanceOf(this));
    contracts.push(c);
    return c;
  }
```

Comment: Ok that looks fine but one thing i want to clear, the generated token address is not actually an address it is a transaction which shows up in the account in metamask.
Is this might be the reason for 0 tokens ?

Comment: Oh, yes, you'll also need to actually get the address of the created contract. Transactions don't have return values, so the `return c` isn't doing anything useful.

Comment: is there any way to get the address of the newly generated contract using a function each time when the new contract is generated using "newToken" function?

Comment: The typical way to do this is to log an event and read it from the transaction receipt.

Comment: I have tried the above code for sending tokens to the caller but that is not working.
Thanks for your previous answers. That helped me alot